# Centering CSS Boxes(Html and Css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to center these boxes in the middle of the screen both horizontally and vertically. Another question is how can I make it where it re-sizes automatically when I scale my page?

```css
/*-------------------------
    Simple reset
--------------------------*/


*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


/*-------------------------
    General Styles
--------------------------*/


/*----------------------------
    Color Themes
-----------------------------*/
.nav-colors{
     position: relative;
      background: white;
      height: 200px;
      width: 60%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
      overflow: auto;
}

.home-link{
    background-color:#00c08b;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.portfolio-link{
    background-color:#ea5080;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;

}
.social-link{
    background-color:#53bfe2;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;

}
.contact-link{
    background-color:#f8c54d;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;

}
.blog-link{
    background-color:#df6dc2;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Neiko Anglin | Front-End Develper </title>

        <!-- Our CSS stylesheet file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

        <!-- Font Awesome Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />


    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav-colors">
            <div class="home-link">
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-link">
            </div>
            <div class="social-link">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-link">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-link">
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning on the container to center vertically and horizontally:

```css
/*-------------------------
    Simple reset
--------------------------*/
 * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/*-------------------------
    General Styles
--------------------------*/

/*----------------------------
    Color Themes
-----------------------------*/
 .nav-colors {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    height: 84px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
.home-link {
    background-color:#00c08b;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.portfolio-link {
    background-color:#ea5080;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.social-link {
    background-color:#53bfe2;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.contact-link {
    background-color:#f8c54d;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.blog-link {
    background-color:#df6dc2;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-colors">
    <div class="home-link"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-link"></div>
    <div class="social-link"></div>
    <div class="contact-link"></div>
    <div class="blog-link"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: One should be careful though when absolutely positioning an element since it removes it from the document flow, thus allowing the parent to collapse - which can cause adverse affects.

Answer (score 0):

To align vertically you need a wrapper class with position absolute in CSS. Search for vertical center which will fetch you lots of results.
To resize boxes along with screen resize - is responsive template. I could suggest you to use Twitter Bootstrap which takes care of your dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.nav-color` class to

```
.nav-colors{
     position: fixed;
      background: white;
      height: 80px;
      width:60%;
      margin: -60px 0 0 0;
      padding: 20px;
      overflow: auto;
      top:50%;
      left:20%;
}
```

```css
/*-------------------------
    Simple reset
--------------------------*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*-------------------------
    General Styles
--------------------------*/

/*----------------------------
    Color Themes
-----------------------------*/

.nav-colors {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  height: 80px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 0;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}
.home-link {
  background-color: #00c08b;
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.portfolio-link {
  background-color: #ea5080;
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.social-link {
  background-color: #53bfe2;
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.contact-link {
  background-color: #f8c54d;
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blog-link {
  background-color: #df6dc2;
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-colors">
  <div class="home-link">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-link">
  </div>
  <div class="social-link">
  </div>
  <div class="contact-link">
  </div>
  <div class="blog-link">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add some properties to your `.nav-colors`:

```
.nav-colors{
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    height: 200px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;

    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And add `vertical-align: middle;` to elements you want to center vertically.

Answer (score 0):

First the explanation, then some code.

Vertical centering is a classic css issue. The `vh` unit has come in very handy for this recently. Coupled with margin (and maybe calc) its now a solvable thing.

Centering it horizontally is simple enough, and you have that figured out. Just have a width and set `margin: 0 auto` and you are good to go.

With Vertical Centering the key thing to remember is you are *centering* your element, so half is over the middle, half is under the middle. With that we can make `margin: calc(50vh-40px) auto 0` for your `80px` high element and presto, it's in the middle vertically.

One step further:
Like horizontal centering, you seem to already have the dynamic width down by using `%`. 
For a dynamic vertical size we can again turn to `vh`. The nice thing is this saves us the css calc function. Just subtract half the height from the 50vh margin and you'll get your margin. So for `height: 20vh` the margin is `margin: 40vh auto 0`

**Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdytubd4/1/)**

and here is some code:

**CSS:**

```
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        html, body{
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .nav-colors{
            width: 80%;
            height: 20vh;
            margin: calc(40vh) auto 0;
        }
        .nav-colors div{
            width: 18%;
            margin: 0 0 0 1%;
            height: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .home-link{background-color:#00c08b;}
        .portfolio-link{background-color:#ea5080;}
        .social-link{background-color:#53bfe2;}
        .contact-link{background-color:#f8c54d;}
        .blog-link{background-color:#df6dc2;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-colors">
    <div class="home-link"></div>
    <div class="portfolio-link"></div>
    <div class="social-link"></div>
    <div class="contact-link"></div>
    <div class="blog-link"></div>
</div>
```

enjoy.